# what's the difference bewteen document.defaultView.getComputedStyle and window.getComputedStyle

Tags: javascript

when get a element's style, we always use

`if(document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle)` to check whether the browser support the method or not.

why not use `if(window.getComputedStyle)`?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle for an explanation + exception (under `defaultView`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So in short, the reason why we use `document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle` is that we want a cross-browser working-on-every-element method of checking whenever it supports fetching computed styles.

Simple `if(window.getComputedStyle)` would fail for iframes in Firefox 3.6 (according to [article linked](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) in comment by Alex K.).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle#defaultview) `defaultView` is no longer required

> In many code samples, getComputedStyle is used from the document.defaultView object. In nearly all cases, this is needless, as getComputedStyle exists on the window object as well. It's likely the defaultView pattern was a combination of folks not wanting to write a testing spec for window and making an API that was also usable in Java.

There was a [bug](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/524#issuecomment-2241183) in Firefox 3.6 (2010/2011) that needed `defaultView` fix