# How to detect text direction of element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, right-to-left

What's the best way to detect the text direction of an html element using Javascript?  I would expect to get either "rtl" or "ltr".

```
<div dir="ltr" id="foo">bar</div>

<div style="direction:ltr" id="baz">quux</div>

<div dir="ltr"><div id="jeez">whiz</div></div>
```

How would I test for the direction on "foo", "baz" or "jeez"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`getComputedStyle` is available in modern browsers (IE9+ and the others).

```
getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('foo')).direction
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m8Zwk/

[Reference to getComputedStyle on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.getComputedStyle)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('baz'),null)['direction'];
```

OR

```
style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.firstChild,null);
console.log(style.direction);
```

Comment: what's the difference between document.defaultView.getComputedStyle and window.getComputedStyle?

Comment: @chowey I don't believe there is one.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136501/whats-the-difference-bewteen-document-defaultview-getcomputedstyle-and-window-g

Answer (score 1):

@explosion-pills answer is correct.  I did some more research for IE compatibility and came up with the following:

```
function getDirection(el) {
    var dir;
    if (el.currentStyle)
        dir = el.currentStyle['direction'];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        dir = getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('direction');
    return dir;
}
```

This should even work on Firefox 3.6 which requires `null` as the second parameter to `getPropertyValue`.

Since this gives more information I thought I would post it in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style) object:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('baz').style.direction);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/B28Hh/)

Take note that this object of the DOM only represents the in-line styles of an element, it doesn't apply to any css style sheets.

Comment: This doesn't work for inherited directions, such as the "jeez" div from above, or stylesheets (as you said).  Inherited direction is actually the most common case.

Comment: @chowey Then I believe you would want explosion's answer.  My bad for mis-interpreting what you wanted.