# how to apply the background from one div to another, in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, background, copy, apply

I'm new to Javascript, but basically what I want to do is get the background from one div's CSS style, and apply it to another div. This is what I have tried but it doesn't work.

```
NewDiv.style.background = OldDiv.style.background;
```

I know that I can do:

```
NewDiv.style.innerHTML = OldDiv.style.inHTML;
```

But I can't seem to do something similar with the CSS background instead of the html. I'm trying to do it with only javascript and no Jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a CSS value with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript)

Comment: @r1k, how you get NewDiv and OldDiv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var element1 = document.getElementById("element1Id");
var element2 = document.getElementById("element2Id");
element2.style.background = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element1).background;
```

If you only want a certain portion of the background styling, instead of all at once, you can use any of the options below instead of "background."

- background-color
- background-image
- background-repeat
- background-attachment
- background-position

more information about background styling can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

If you are curious why I used "document.defaultView.getComputedStyle" instead of "window.getComputedStyle" feel free to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136501/whats-the-difference-bewteen-document-defaultview-getcomputedstyle-and-window-g) StackOverflow Q/A that answers that question.

TL:DR; "document.defaultView.getComputedStyle" will work in all browsers

Comment: thanks, but its not quite what I want to achieve. I dont want to copy all the styles of the first div, just the background. The other styles defines for the second div should stay intact

Comment: oh gotcha, it's fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `someElement.style.backgroundColor`:

```
var oldDiv = document.getElementById('old');
var newDiv = document.getElementById('new');

newDiv.style.backgroundColor = oldDiv.style.backgroundColor;
```

More info: [Style backgroundColor Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp)